# Creating a simple program drawing rectanges

Tags: java, arrays, object, draw

I am a beginner Java coder and I am working on a assignment for class. We have to make a rectangle class and a driver class. The point of the program is to draw rectangles with the '#' symbol based on user input of how many rows, columns, and if it is filled. So far I have everything but the filled or not filled logic. For example if I put 3 rows and 3 columns and it is filled it would look like this:

```
###
###
###
```

if it was the same thing but not filled it would look like this:

```
###
# #
###
```

Please look at my rectangle class and driver class and see if you can help!

```
public class rectangle {

    private int numRows;        // The number of rows
    private int numCols;        // The number of columns
    private boolean filled;     // The boolean to determine if the rectangle is filled or unfilled


    // initialize variables
    public rectangle() { 
        numRows = 1;
        numCols = 1;
        filled = false;
    }

    /**
     * @param rows
     * @param cols
     */
    public rectangle(int numRows,int numCols){
        setRows(numRows);
        setCols(numCols);
        setFilled(filled);
    }

    // getters and setters
    public int getRows() {
        return numRows;
    }

    public void setRows(int numRows) {
        this.numRows = numRows;
    }

    public int getCols() {
        return numCols;
    }

    public void setCols(int numCols) {
        this.numCols = numCols;
    }

    public boolean getFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    // Create and return string for output
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(filled = true){
        for(int i = 0; i < numRows;i++){
            for(int a = 0; a < numCols;a++){
            System.out.print("#");
        }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        }

        if(filled = false){
            // need this part
            }   


        return "rectangle [numRows=" + numRows + ", numCols=" + numCols
                + ", filled=" + filled + "]";
    }
}
```

and my driver class:

```
public class Lab1ADriver {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // create scanner
         Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        // create printwriter
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("rectangleData.txt");

        // Ask user for input
        System.out.print("How many rectangles will you be using?");
        int numRec = kb.nextInt();
        output.println(numRec);

        // write to file
        for(int i=0; i < numRec; i++){
            System.out.print("How many rows are in the rectangle?");
            int numRows = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.print("How many columns are in the rectangle?");
            int numCols = kb.nextInt(); 
            System.out.println("Is rectangle filled? (y/n)");
            String filled = kb.next();

            // write vars to text file      
            output.println(numRows + " " + numCols + " " + filled);
        }
        // close scanner and pw
        kb.close();
        output.close();

        // array list to hold rectangle objects
        ArrayList<rectangle> box = new ArrayList<rectangle>();

        // open file for reading
        File inFile = new File("rectangleData.txt");
        Scanner recFile = new Scanner(inFile);

        // read data and add rectangle objects to array list
        recFile.nextLine();
        while(recFile.hasNext()){
            rectangle a = new rectangle();
            // read next line
            String recData = recFile.nextLine();

            // extract number of rows 
            String rowData = recData.substring(0, 1);
            rowData = rowData.trim();
            int numRows = Integer.parseInt(rowData);

            // extract columns
            String colData = recData.substring(1, 3);
            colData = colData.trim();
            int numCols = Integer.parseInt(colData);

            // extract boolean filled
            String fillData = recData.substring(3, 5);
            fillData = fillData.trim();
            char f = fillData.charAt(0);
            if (f == 'y'){
                a.setFilled(true);
            }
            else {
                a.setFilled(false) ;
            }


            a.setRows(numRows);
            a.setCols(numCols);     
            // add rectangle object to arraylist
            box.add(a);     
        }   
        recFile.close();    
        box.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that take as input the actual row and column that you are drawing and that return true if you are at the border or false if not.

If that function return true draw a '#' or not if the function return false.

Obviously, use that function only if you are in the not filled case.

```
// Create and return string for output
@Override
public String toString() {
    for(int i = 0; i < numRows;i++){
        for(int a = 0; a < numCols;a++)
        {
            if (amIAtTheBorder(i,a) || filled)
            {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I get what you mean, but still have not figured out the logic to make a amIAtTheBorder method.

Comment: just think a bit on it, if a or i are 0 for sure you are at a border, pass also numRows and numCols to that function (that for real should be a method of your class, so that method would have access to those values) and you can know if you are on one of the other borders